# iPhone application crashing when presenting view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, ios-simulator

I'm working on an iPhone project using Xcode and I actually have not programmed using Objective-C before.

So, my problem mainly is that my app crashes whenever I hit the button that it suppose to show a view of the world map. I think the problem is within the last 2 lines of the code but still I cant figure out why! Because whenever I comment out the line `[self presemtM…]` the program doesn't crash.

Would appreciate your help!

```
-(IBAction) pushedGo:(id)sender
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {37.331689, -122.030731};

    MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithCoordinates:coord    andTitle:@"Apple" andSubTitle:@"111"];

   [self presentModalViewController:mapView animated:YES]

   [mapView release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
the problem was that the mapKit.framework was not added !!

***My answer was in the comments, and I just added it here.

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {37.331689, -122.030731}; isn't correct, so that's probably what's crashing your app.

Comment: i tried to fix it but still the same problem!! I actually had the exact same problem when i tried to request a URL page but unfortunately didn't know what was causing the problem.

Comment: OK I got this from the console window: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MKMapView)'

Comment: No code in your question contains that NSKeyedArchiver. Maybe post more of your code.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with a missing framework, but I am glad you got it resolved! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late for your but it could be helpful for others.

I just had the same issue. The trick was that the framework was not included properly.

It was listed among the other frameworks used in the left hand pane of xcode within the tree of sources and resources. But for some reason it was not listed within the frameworks in the Build phases of each (!) target.

Answer (score 0):

Add http://www.hockeyapp.net/ to your App. It is designed to provide you with good debug information.